# How to create draggable circle in flutter map

Tags: flutter, maps, fluttermap

I need to create a draggable circle in a flutter map with a 500-meter radius  and I don't want to use Google maps

I created Container and add it to the inside of the DragMarker widget in Flutter map, but when the user zoom in or zoom out  the map I m  unable to maintain a 500m radius in that case. any suggestions are much appreciated

here is my full code

```
import 'package:findmypet_flutter/contoller/dialog_helper.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_map/flutter_map.dart';
import 'package:flutter_map_dragmarker/flutter_map_dragmarker.dart';
import 'package:latlong2/latlong.dart';
import 'package:logger/logger.dart';

class MapScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final LatLng location;
  const MapScreen({super.key, required this.location});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool isdrag = true;
    double circleRadius = 100.0; // Adjust as per your requirement
    Color circleBorderColor = Colors.blue; // Initial border color
    double circleBorderWeight = 5.0; // Initial border weight
    LatLng? markedLatlnag;
    final Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          heroTag: null,
          child: const Icon(Icons.add_location_alt_outlined),
          onPressed: () {
            DialogHelper.showConfirmationDialog(
                context, "Are You sure this is the correct Location", () {
              if (markedLatlnag != null) {
                Logger().wtf(markedLatlnag);
                DialogHelper.showSuccessDialog(
                    context, markedLatlnag.toString(), () => null, true);
              } else {}
            });
          },
        ),
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("Set the location"),
        ),
        body: FlutterMap(
          nonRotatedChildren: const [],
          mapController: MapController(),
          options: MapOptions(
            minZoom: 11.0,
            maxZoom: 17.0,
            interactiveFlags: InteractiveFlag.pinchZoom | InteractiveFlag.drag,
            zoom: 13.0,
            center: location,
            // Adjust the multiplier as needed
          ),
          children: [
            TileLayer(
              urlTemplate: 'https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
              userAgentPackageName: 'com.example.app',
            ),
            DragMarkers(
              markers: [
                DragMarker(
                  rotateMarker: false,
                  size: Size(circleRadius * 2, circleRadius * 2),
                  point: markedLatlnag ?? location,
                  offset: const Offset(0.0, -8.0),
                  builder: (context, demoMarkers, isdrag) => Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    color: const Color.fromARGB(55, 41, 120, 255),
                    border: Border.all(
                      color: circleBorderColor,
                      width: circleBorderWeight,
                    ),
                  )),
                  onDragUpdate: (details, latLng) => print(latLng),
                  onDragEnd: (details, latLng) {
                    // Update the marker's position

                    markedLatlnag = latLng;
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```